# In Expendable List View, setting data in Global array list under group for loop, when getting in Adapter, it is showing only last value?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In Expandable List view , before setting adapter , i am setting data in global array list in group loop,when i cheek in log in that loop, data is coming as it is what i want, but when get data outside the loop or in adapter class , it save only last value .

Please check code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

public static View view;
public static ExpandableListView 
recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView;
public static ProgressBar progress_onHome_Act_mProgressBar;
public static GroupsAdapter groupsAdapter;
public static ArrayList<Group> groupsList;
public static ArrayList<Child> child_list;
```

public static ArrayList legListArrayList;

```
public static JsonElement title_mJSonElement, chase_truck_mJsonElement, connote_url_mJSonElement,
        container_number_mJSonElement, fleet_numbermJSonElement, driver_name_mJSonElement,
        freight_type_mJSonElement, from_cust_city_mJSonElement;
public static JsonElement  leg_id_mJSonElement;
public static Child childClass;
public static Group groupClass;
public static Context context;
public static String[] colors = new String[]{"#2E9AFE", "#58FAF4", "#D8F781", "#FF00FF", "#9AFE2E", "#F5DA81", "#0B0B3B", "#D8F781", "#F2F5A9", "#1E90FF",    "#6495ED", "#7B68EE", "#8A2BE2", "#E6Ef6FA"};
public static JsonObject gettingDataFromMainArray_mJSonObject;
public static JSONObject jsonObjForJobInfo;
public static ArrayList keys_of_JobInfo_mArrayList;
public static ArrayList values_of_JobInfo_mArrayList;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> document_mArrayListHashMap;
public static ArrayList<String> document_mArrayList;
public static ArrayList<String> CANNOTE_mArrayList;
public static String key, _pubKey;
public static JSONObject jsonResult;
public static ArrayList<String> tetsingg;
public static ArrayList<String> fdata;


public static HomeFragment newInstance(int page) {
    HomeFragment fragmentFirst = new HomeFragment();

  Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    inits();


    return view;
}

private void inits() {
    context = getActivity();
    Fontchange.overrideFonts(context, view.findViewById(R.id.home_mRelativeLayout));

    recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView);
    groupsList = new ArrayList<Group>();
    child_list = new ArrayList<Child>();
    childClass = new Child();
    showProgressDialog(context);
    GettingsMainLegLIst();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public static void GettingsMainLegLIst() {


  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String ss = "https://testing.freighttracker.com.au/";
    int pageNum = 1;
    int pageSize = 3;
    final String url = ss + "api/GetLegList" + "?" + "&useraccesstoken=" + GlobalClass.getAccessToken() + "&PageNumber=" + pageNum + "&PageSize=" + pageSize;
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("responseReso", "--" + url);
            cancelProgressDialog();
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> frndListpost = new ArrayList<>();
            JsonObject mainResponse_mJsonObject = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(response);
            Log.e("HomeFragment", "" + mainResponse_mJsonObject);
            JsonObject dataObj_mJsonObject = mainResponse_mJsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

            JsonElement errorElemnt = dataObj_mJsonObject.get("leg_list");
            if (errorElemnt.isJsonObject()) {
                Log.e("JsonObject", "--" + errorElemnt.isJsonObject());
                JsonObject legListObj_mJsonObject = dataObj_mJsonObject.get("leg_list").getAsJsonObject();
                JSONArray gettingDocumentArray_mJsonArray;
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> dynamic_ObjOF_Group : legListObj_mJsonObject.entrySet()) {
                    fdata = new ArrayList<String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap_post = new HashMap<>();
                    JsonArray gotGroups_mJsonArray = dynamic_ObjOF_Group.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
                    groupClass = new Group();
                    groupClass.setName(dynamic_ObjOF_Group.getKey());
                    child_list = new ArrayList<Child>();

                          // Intialize  Arraylist in group loop;
                    legListArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    tetsingg = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < gotGroups_mJsonArray.size(); i++) {

                        document_mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        document_mArrayListHashMap = new ArrayList<>();

                        HashMap<String, String> cannoteHashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        String cannote = "http://ft.yurtest.net/drivers.document.connot/2300";
                        cannoteHashMap.put("cannote", cannote);
                        document_mArrayListHashMap.add(cannoteHashMap);

                        keys_of_JobInfo_mArrayList = new ArrayList();
                        values_of_JobInfo_mArrayList = new ArrayList();
                        CANNOTE_mArrayList = new ArrayList();

                        gettingDataFromMainArray_mJSonObject = gotGroups_mJsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        childClass = new Child();
                        childClass.setColors(colors);
                        try {
                            jsonResult = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(gettingDataFromMainArray_mJSonObject));
                            gettingDocumentArray_mJsonArray = jsonResult.getJSONArray("document");

                            for (int array = 0; array < gettingDocumentArray_mJsonArray.length(); array++) {
                                if (gettingDocumentArray_mJsonArray.length() == 0) {

                                } else {
                                    String filename = gettingDocumentArray_mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("filename");
                                    String document_url = gettingDocumentArray_mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("document_url");
                                    HashMap<String, String> documentHashMapData = new HashMap<>();
                                    documentHashMapData.put("filename", filename);
                                    documentHashMapData.put("document_url", document_url);
                                    document_mArrayListHashMap.add(documentHashMapData);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        childClass.setDocument_mArrayList(document_mArrayListHashMap);
                        document_mArrayList.add(String.valueOf(document_mArrayListHashMap.size()));
                        job_info_mJSonElement = gettingDataFromMainArray_mJSonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("job_info");
                        if (job_info_mJSonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                            try {
                                jsonObjForJobInfo = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(gettingDataFromMainArray_mJSonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("job_info")));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Iterator iterators = jsonObjForJobInfo.keys();
                            while (iterators.hasNext()) {
                                key = (String) iterators.next();
                                _pubKey = jsonObjForJobInfo.optString(key);
                                keys_of_JobInfo_mArrayList.add(key);
                                values_of_JobInfo_mArrayList.add(_pubKey);
                            }
                        } else if (job_info_mJSonElement.isJsonArray()) {
                        }



                  leg_id_mJSonElement = gotGroups_mJsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject().get("leg_id");

                //Setting data in  Arraylist ;

                        legListArrayList.add(String.valueOf(leg_id_mJSonElement));
                        fdata.add(String.valueOf(leg_id_mJSonElement));

                     groupClass.setItems(child_list);

                    //Setting   Arraylist  in  Groupmodel class;

                    groupClass.setLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList(legListArrayList);
                    groupsList.add(groupClass);

                    //Now , when i am getting data inside the loop, getting same data as it is i want.




                }
              //But  , when i am getting data outside the loop, it saves last value only




                groupsAdapter = new GroupsAdapter(context, groupsList);
                childClass.setColors(colors);
                recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView.setAdapter(groupsAdapter);

            } else if (errorElemnt.isJsonArray()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Data!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("JSONArray", "--" + errorElemnt.isJsonArray());
            }
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: please add your snippet of code.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @RatilalChopda I have posted code, please help

Comment: @Jack Please check

Comment: This code is not runnable. Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)